# (Codeigniter) Can I use default controller with parameter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, default

Hello friends I'm working with codeigniter but I need your help.

I'm using the default controller like:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'generals/view/index';
```

But when I enter to my localhost I see the 404 error.

I show my controller bellow.

```
public function view($page){
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('sections/'.$page);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

I would be greatful for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Codeigniter Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=default_controller#reserved-routes), **default_controller** is a reserved route:

```
This route points to the action that should be executed if the URI contains no data,
which will be the case when people load your root URL. The setting accepts a 
controller/method value and index() would be the default method if you don’t specify 
one. In the above example, it is Welcome::index() that would be called.
```

Please update your **default_controller** to:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'generals/view';
```

and in your controller

```
public function view($page = 'index'){
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('sections/'.$page);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

For the rest of uri's, you need to define another route(s).